# Deriving the Poisson equation for pressure

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to derive the Poisson equation for pressure, specifically that $$\bigtriangledown^2(p + \frac{1}{2}|\vec{u}|^2) = \bigtriangledown \cdot(\vec{u}\times \vec{w}) + \varepsilon \kappa^2\psi\cdot\bigtriangledown\phi $$ where the vorticity field is given by $$w = \bigtriangledown\times \vec{u}$$
I am unsure how to manipulate the left-hand side to reach the right-hand side.I know that I can write $$|\vec{u}|^2 = |\bigtriangledown\phi|^2 = |\bigtriangledown\psi|^2$$ But I am unsure what else I can do.This problem is in reference to a particular paper I am reading,so some of the notation on the RHS may not be known without context,however,I just need help with the manipulation of the LHS.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\nabla$ (`\nabla`) is the standard symbol for div ($\nabla\cdot$), grad ($\nabla$), and curl ($\nabla\times$).

Comment: What's $\phi$ and $\psi$? and $\kappa,\epsilon$?

Comment: I would guess that you obtain the Poisson equation by starting with the equation with $ \nabla p$ in it and taking the divergence of the equation. Massaging it into that form for you would require more context, since its not clear at all what kind of fluid you're dealing with